# Why is there unique plane which passes through given point and is parallel to given line

Tags: analytic-geometry

I was trying to solve one question which is asking to find a plane which passes through given point and is parallel to given line.

The given point is $M(2,-5,3)$ and the given line is given as an interesection of the planes $2x-y+3z-1=0 \text{ and } 5x+4y-z-7=0$

It is still unclear for me why there is only one unique plane which can be answer, I think that there are more possible planes that can be answers to this.

Comment: Perhaps you might include the specific problem that you’re asking about.

Comment: I inserted the given point and the line into the post

Comment: Are you sure that the problem said for the plane to be parallel to that line? If it must instead include the line, then the solution is be unique.

Comment: Yes, the question is asking about plane which is parallel to the given line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are right, such plane is not unique. For example the planes $2x-y+3z=18$ and $5x+4y-z=-13$ pass through the point $(2,-5,3)$ and they are parallel to the given line.

More generally, through the given point, there is a **unique line** parallel  to the given line, but then **any plane** through this second line is parallel to the given line.

Comment: I'm thinking like this, but my teacher gave some explanation that I didn't really understand. She says that there is only one such plane

Comment: Maybe the problem was "find a plane which passes through a given point and it is **orthogonal** to a given line.

Comment: Or perhaps the plane is supposed to include the intersection line of the two given planes (see updated question). Impossible to know without seeing the teacher’s solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are right: there are infinitely mane planes passing through a point and parallel to a given line.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer points out, the claim is false.  Given a set of planes *parallel to each other* as well as to the given line, only one of those planes will pass through the given point.